# How to connect Visual FoxPro in Windows 2012 R2

Tags: vb.net, vb6, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using Visual FoxPro and Visual FoxPro odbc driver.

My code was working fine in Windows Server 2003. Now we need to migrate to Windows Server 2012 R2. We installed visual odbc driver on server. Still it is not working. We have also registered application DLL (developed in Vb 6) in syswow64 folder. However no luck.

Below is my code:

```
Dim strDbfstring
Strdbfstring = "Driver = {microsoft visual FoxPro driver };sourcetype= dbf;Exclusive = no"
Condbf.open strdbfstring
```

Answer (score 1):

The code for oledb provider 9.0 works for me. The only problem was in installation setting. I re-installed oledb driver with permission for everyone. Provider should have given access to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The old Desktop ODBC Drivers have always had their limitations.  I'm not sure they were ever made available as redistributables.  VFP could be an exception.  However:

> The VFPODBC driver is no longer supported. We strongly recommend using the Visual FoxPro OLE DB provider as a replacement.

So have you considered [Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Visual FoxPro 9.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839) instead?  This will probably be far more robust anyway.

Comment: We installed  Microsoft oledb provider for visual foxpro 9.0. Error comes provider not found. (Error code 3706). Can anybody help me for the same.Do I need excel on server??

Comment: Besides all dbf files (template files) are stored in specific folder

Comment: I tried  with strDBFConnString = "provider = vpfoledb.1; data source = " & strdestpath & "; collating Sequence = machine"